# Clang 8.0.1 always creates console application on Windows

Tags: windows, console-application, clang++

When I build an app on Windows using Clang 8.0.1 (sadly the newer ones are a bit buggy here), it always generates a console application. `-mwindows` doesn't seem to do anything, and `-Wl,--subsystem,windows` ends up with a silly error `windows.obj cannot be found`. And the linker also says "no subsystem specified, CONSOLE assumed", but I didn't find any way to actually specify the subsystem.

Any ideas? This way the compiler is pretty much useless unless I make a console app or a DLL.

Edit: I'm using clang++, not clang_cl

Comment: "*the newer ones are a bit buggy*" What do you mean?

Comment: [/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Acorn: Generated buggy code. Afaik it's been worked on in 10.0.1, but the compiled version is not available yet. RbMm: I'm using clang++, not clang_cl

Comment: I see, thanks. Are you using the `WinMain` (or however it is written, I don't recall) or `main`?

Comment: what linker you use ?

Comment: I use clang++ again

Comment: Acorn: I believe I include implementation of both (it's a bigger framework).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is caused by the existence of "main" function. While I already had "WinMain" present, apparently Clang prioritizes "main" making it a console app.